# How to comparison two date without seconds in C

Tags: c

I want to comparison two dates, one at the current datetime and one memorized in a list.
If these dates have the same year, month and day, I add a value to the old date in the list: if not, I create a new elements in the list.

```
struct entry{
time_t date;
int quantity;
struct entry* next;
};
```

I call the `find_list`, to find and compare the current date and the date memorized

```
    int find_list(struct entry* head, time_t data, int quantita){

    struct tm* data_value, *data_list;  
    struct entry* pointer = head;
    time(&data);    
    data_value = gmtime(&data); 

    while(pointer){     
        data_list = gmtime(&pointer->date);
        //printf("Tempo value:%s\nTempo lista: %s\n", asctime(data_value), asctime(data_list));
        if(data_value->tm_year == data_list->tm_year && .....){
            pointer->quantity += quantita;
            return 1; 
        }
        pointer = pointer->next;        
    }
    return 0;   
};
```

but if I printf the two value, I print equals value

Comment: Unix and POSIX measure time as the number of seconds that have passed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 known as the Unix epoch. So if you divide the seconds by 86400 (seconds per day) that should give the days since the start of the Epoch, which you can compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gmtime()` returns a pointer. Consecutive calls to `gmtime()` (all returning a pointer) may return a pointer to the same memory.

Copy the memory pointed to to a real object.

```
struct tm data_list;                 // not a pointer!
data_list = *gmtime(&pointer->data); // copy value
```

*Note: POSIX introduced [`gmtime_r()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gmtime.html), which behaves as expected.*

```
// for POSIX systems
struct tm data_list;                  // still not a pointer
gmtime_r(&pointer->data, &data_list);
```

Comment: Uh! Nasty one. :)

Comment: If I use the gmtime_r, how could I make the comparaison?

Comment: like in your question: `if (data_value->tm_year == data_list->tm_year && .....) {`

Comment: He told me "invalid type of argument '->' (have 'struct tm')

Comment: Ah... use `.`, not `->`... `if (data_value.tm_year == data_list.tm_year && .....) {`